# Build error when compiling Tailwind CSS in the broswer

Tags: node.js, reactjs, tailwind-css

I've created a simple demo app in code sandbox to compile Tailwind CSS in the browser. It works fine but when trying to recreate the app locally (using the exact same code) it keeps coming up with the following error during the initial compilation, related to `utils.promisify`:

`TypeError: The "original" argument must be of type Function.`

I'm at a loss for why this won't work locally when it runs fine via code sandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/quizzical-einstein-27bn1?file=/src/App.js

Any ideas what could be the issue?